# android - How to handle error by using LiveData and RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-livedata

I'm new for learning [android architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/) and I have stuck in the question several days.

I use [LiveDataReactiveStreams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams) to transform Livedata and Flowable, all of them works well, except handling RxJava's onError.

```
        livedata = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            // bookRepository.getAll() return a Flowable
            bookRepository.getAll().map {
                val allBookNames = mutableListOf<String>()
                it.forEach {
                    allBookNames.add(it.name)
                }
                return@map allBookNames.toList()
            }
        )
```

I saw [How to handle error states with LiveData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208618/how-to-handle-error-states-with-livedata)
 and figure out I can

1. wrap my data to Handle my error
2. or use MediatorLiveData as @[Nikola Despotoski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557179/nikola-despotoski) said, but there is an another question is Flowable onComplete() is never called.

Is there a better way to solve this question or any details about these two solutions I've ignored?

Comment: I think you need to use LiveData instead of RxJava. They're both observables.

Comment: @Hades But LiveData also doesn't provide any functions to handle errors.

Comment: Depending on the implementation of your `bookRepository.getAll()` method, you could pass an error callback there as a parameter, and change the call to the following:

    bookRepository.getAll({//Handle error here}).map {//Handle success here}.etc...

With this approach, your `getAll()` method would fire the callback and return null in case of error, or return the books in case of success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(
            Observable.just(1,2)
                    .map { LiveDataResult(it, null) }
                    .onErrorReturn {
                        it.printStackTrace()
                        LiveDataResult(null, it)
                    }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.MISSING)


class LiveDataResult<T>(val data: T?, val error: Throwable?)
```

Then inUI you can handle result or error